# Ruby: How to iterate through a hash created from a csv file

Tags: ruby, loops, csv, hash

I am trying to take an existing CSV file, add a fourth row to it, and then iterate through the second and third row to create the fourth rows values. Using Ruby I've created hashes where the headers are the keys and the column values are the hash values (ex: "id"=>"1", "new_fruit" => "apple")

My practice CSV file looks like this:[practice csv file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlugW.png)

My goal is to create a fourth column: "brand_new" (which I was able to do) and then add values to it by concatenating the values from the second and third row (which I am stuck on). At the moment I just have a placement value (x) for the fourth columns values so I could see if adding the fourth column to the hash actually worked: [Results with x = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0q7Y.png)

Here is my code:

```
require 'csv'

def self.import  
  table = []
  CSV.foreach(File.path("practice.csv"), headers: true) do |row|
    table.each do |row| 
      row["brand_new"] = full_name
    end
    table << row.to_h
  end
  table
 end

def full_name
  x = 1
  return x
end

# Add another col, row by row:
import.each do |row|
  row["brand_new"] = full_name
end
puts import
```

Any suggestions or guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't link to pictures of code or data. If users want to use it to demonstrate code you are forcing them to copy values by hand. By making it text readers can simply cut-and-paste. Also, links have a habit of breaking.

Comment: @CarySwoveland My apologies, next time I will definitely just use text instead of photos

Answer (score 1):

Simplified your code a bit. I read the file first, then iterate about the read content.

Note: Change `col_sep` to comma or delete it to use the default if needed.

```
require "csv"

def self.import 
  table = CSV.read("practice.csv", headers: true , col_sep: ";")

  table.each do |row|
    row["brand_new"] = "#{row["old_fruit"]} #{row["new_fruit"]}"
  end
  puts table
end
```

I use the read method to read the CSV file content. It allows you to directly access the column/cell values.

Line 7 shows how to concatenate the column values as string:

```
"#{row["old_fruit"]} #{row["new_fruit"]}"
```

Refer to [this old SO pos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379909/how-can-i-add-a-column-to-a-csv-file)t and the [CSV Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-read) to learn more about working with CSV files.

Comment: Thank you @Christian so much for your help, I really appreciate it! And thank you for the links, I'll be sure to take a look at both of them